# mqsicreatebar command, packaging issue

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

Working on mqsicreatebar command to create a bar file using below command

---

```
            <echo level="info">[ibmwmqcreateBar] Calling mqsicreatebar, this may take several minutes </echo>
        <exec dir="@{workspacedirectory}"
        executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WMBT700\mqsicreatebar.exe"
        spawn="false"
        newenvironment="false"
        searchpath="true"
        failonerror="false"
        vmlauncher="false"
        resultproperty="exec.returnvalue"
        logError="true"
        output="@{barfilename}.log"
        error="@{barfilename}_err.log">
            <env key="CLASSPATH" value="@{classpath}"/>
            <arg value="-cleanBuild "/>
            <arg value="-data"/>
            <arg value="@{workspacedirectory}"/>
            <arg value="-b"/>
            <arg value="@{barfilename}"/>
            <arg value="-p"/>
            <arg line="@{projectnames}"/>
            <arg value="-o"/>
            <arg line="@{filepaths}"/>
            <arg line="-trace"/>
        </exec>
```

---

The problem is I want to exclude one of the projectnames from being packaged with the bar. Its only required during compilation and not required for packaging.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario.  I had a separate java project that contained shared code among all of my applications.  I had to change the build path to reference the bin file, instead of the entire project.  When I did this the shared code was not included in the package, I deployed the shared code separately.